# The good and the bad: Coda or Espresso?

Tags: mac, web-development, text-editors

For my semi-professional web development studio, I'd like to use a more dedicated piece of software in stead of plain text editors.

Both Coda as Espresso seem interesting, but I can't seem to choose which one to buy. Any thoughts on which one to choose?

Comment: Why not try TextMates heh

Comment: Unless there one choice is really better than another, this should be Community Wiki

Comment: @Ivo Flipse - Agree. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't tried Expresso, but did used Coda for a while. I was using it for webdesign jobs (HTML+CSS) as it is very cool for it.

But as soon as the HTML Structure and CSS Styles were in place, a switched to a more code-oriented editor.

I'm now using TextMate from the beginning to the end. It's soooo powerful, it's like a game to write HTML, CSS, JS, Ruby, etc...

Like mgpyone commented, why not try it!

Answer (score 1):

I tried Espresso for a short while and was not impressed. It seemed like a beefed up CSS editor with some stuff slapped on.

I also tried Coda for a while. My favorite feature was the "Publish" button. After that, the lack luster editor and lack of readily available code editing tools kinda got to me. It's pitched as a "one window web development" but honestly it's not. It's one window with tabs. Each tab is a separate program. It might be better if they ditched SubEthaEdit and replaced it with something like **[TextMate](http://macromates.com/)**, along with changing the window layout.

In short, if you're going to go IDE, go full IDE. Pay a bunch of money for something that does just about everything.

Otherwise, TextMate.

[image: TextMate]